Count based window in kafka-streams
I am new to kafka and kafka-streams and have been exploring. In addition to that, i am new to Java too.
But anyway, I have this problem where I want to create tumbling windows of these messages that are being published to a kafka topic, and these windows are not time-based but rather, these are count based. Basically, for each entity, I want to create a window with the last n items in it, irrespective of whether these messages were received in the last 1 day or 10 days.
I have observed from the documentation that kafka-streams provide time-based windows but there should be a way to do this count-based windows too, And then when I have a window of n messages I want to publish this window to a new topic, and then start creating a new window from the next message. Can anyone help me with that or at least point me in the right direction?
I have tried the time-based windows but that doesn't solve my problem.

Kafka Streams does not have built-in count-based windows.
You would need to use the lower-lever Processor API (PAPI) and build a custom Processor with attached state store and implement the logic you need manually.
For example, you could use a KeyValueStore and store a <key, List<value>> to accumulate a list of n value per key, and when the list reaches n, do your computation and send a result down stream, and clear the list to start a new window.
Cf https://kafka.apache.org/37/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html
